# stretching winform with graphics

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I'm writing a game using c#'s winforms,
When creating a Scene (holding graphics, objects, etc...) I'm transfering the form so the c'tor looks something like that:

```
public Scene(Form form)
{
    _g = form.CreateGraphics();
    RegisterFormEvents(form);
    _gameObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    Width = form.Width;
    Height = form.Height;
}
```

Now I'm trying to add an option to show the game on full screen,
but when i'm trying to maximize the window it only prints graphics to the original Width x Height,
how can I strecth those?

Comment: that's because you already get the forms Width and Height after you resize it ..where are you getting and assigning the Width and Height again.. this does not happen magically..

Comment: How does the code make use of `_g = form.CreateGraphics()`.  There are very few valid reasons for you to ever call `CreateGraphics` and retain a reference like that.

Comment: `g = form.CreateGraphics();`  This is basically __always__ wrong.To draw scales you can call `Graphics.ScaleTransform`, but you need to understand which `Graphics` object to use in the first place and your code is bound to fail..

Answer (score 0):

You just have to listen to the [SizeChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the form. Whenever the size has changed you set the Width and Height properties of the scene to match the new dimensions.

So, somewhere in your code you should have the following:

```
// I assume that this code is in the code-behind of the form, so "this" is the form 
this.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(FormSizeChanged);
```

and

```
private void FormSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourScene.Width = this.Width;
    yourScene.Height = this.Height;
}
```

Comment: If i do so, it won't stretch

Comment: Have you checked with the debugger that the SizeChanged event actually fires and you handle it correctly? Whenever the form is maximized, its size changes (unless it happens to already be the same size as it would be when maximized) and the event fires. If that doesn't work, I suspect there's something wrong with how you draw things.